# error in the deploying of my first ERC20 tokken

Tags: erc-20

I'm trying to deploy my first ERC20 token.

When I compile my basic code (that I write based on a guide) there is no problem but when I try to deploy him, there is an error: `This contract may be abstract, not implement an abstract parent's methods completely or not invoke an inherited contract's constructor correctly.`

I think it's a basic error but I don't understand why it's happening.

Can you please help me?

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract ERC20Interface {
    function totalSupply() public  view returns (uint);
    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public  view returns (uint);
    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public  view returns (uint);
    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public  returns (bool );
    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public  returns (bool );
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public  returns (bool);

    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint tokens);
    event Approval(address indexed tokenOwner, address indexed spender, uint tokens);
}

contract SafeMath {
    function safeAdd(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
        c = a + b;
        require(c >= a);
    }
    function safeSub(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) {
        require(b <= a); c = a - b; } function safeMul(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) { c = a * b; require(a == 0 || c / a == b); } function safeDiv(uint a, uint b) public pure returns (uint c) { require(b > 0);
        c = a / b;
    }

}


contract IPES_coin is ERC20Interface, SafeMath {
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals; 

    uint256 public _totalSupply;

    mapping(address => uint) balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) allowed;

    constructor() public {
        name = "IPES_coin";
        symbol = "IPESC";
        decimals = 18;
        _totalSupply = 100000000000000000000000000;

        balances[msg.sender] = _totalSupply;
        emit Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, _totalSupply);
    }

     function totalSupply() public  view returns (uint) {
        return _totalSupply  - balances[address(0)];
    }

    function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public  view returns (uint) {
        return balances[tokenOwner];
    }

    function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public view returns (uint) {
        return allowed[tokenOwner][spender];
    }

    function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool) {
        allowed[msg.sender][spender] = tokens;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, tokens);
        return true;
    }

    function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool) {
        balances[msg.sender] = safeSub(balances[msg.sender], tokens);
        balances[to] = safeAdd(balances[to], tokens);
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, tokens);
        return true;
    }

    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool) {
        balances[from] = safeSub(balances[from], tokens);
        allowed[from][msg.sender] = safeSub(allowed[from][msg.sender], tokens);
        balances[to] = safeAdd(balances[to], tokens);
        emit Transfer(from, to, tokens);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Contract `IPES_coin` inherits from contract `ERC20Interface`, which declares the following functions:

```
function totalSupply() external view returns (uint256);
function balanceOf(address account) external view returns (uint256);
function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
function allowance(address owner, address spender) external view returns (uint256);
function approve(address spender, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
function transferFrom(address sender, address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool);
```

Hence it must implement each one of these functions in order to be deployable.

It seems that you have indeed implemented all of these functions, but then declared each one of them as `public` instead of `external`.

So change it in one place to match the other (I'd recommend changing `external` to `public` rather than vice-versa, because that's pretty much the standard in ERC20 tokens).

Also, in each one of the following functions:

```
function balanceOf(address tokenOwner) public view returns (uint balance) { ... }
function allowance(address tokenOwner, address spender) public view returns (uint remaining) { ... }
function approve(address spender, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) { ... }
function transfer(address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) { ... }
function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint tokens) public returns (bool success) { ... }
```

You need to get rid of the return-value name, because these functions otherwise return these (initialized-by-default-to-zero) variables, meaning in your case, `0`s and `false`s.

Comment: thank you for your answer but I don't get it, if I must get rid of the return-value name what must I return? a `true` or somthing else? And how can I change the contract of `ERC20Interface` to change it in `public`? P.S: I'm a real newbie and I don't really know what I'm doing so forgive me if I ask stupid question :) .

Comment: @Endurs: Just get rid of that name in the function declaration, for example, change `returns(bool success)` to `returns(bool)`. Otherwise, the compiler ignores your `return true` statement at the end of the function, and returns the value of the `success` variable (which is `false` by default). BTW, as an alternative to that, you can replace the `return true` statement with `success = true`, and you'd get the same result (i.e., the compiler will return the value of the `success` variable even though you would have no `return` statement at the end of the function). Do you understand now?

Comment: @Endurs: As to your second question - do you not have access to the source code of contract `ERC20Interface`???

Comment: no I don't have the sourc code but I temporarily change the `public` in `external` and make the change that you advised and my contract is still abstract.

Comment: @Endurs: No you didn't!!! I can see in that piece of code that you've posted as an answer (please delete it BTW), that you're still using `returns (uint balance)`, `returns (uint remaining)`, `returns (bool success)` and so forth!!!

Comment: Ho my bad, I just change it. So what do you think of my new code? (I edited my question).

Comment: @goodvibration: "You need to get rid of the return-value name" - that's not true.  Try this: `function returnTest() public pure returns (bool test) {
        test = true;
        return false;
    }` - and you'll see that it returns `test = false`

Comment: @Zakalwe: The *abstract contract* issue is answered in the first part of my answer, and is unrelated to that. Nevertheless, it's still a good practice to avoid both using return-value name in the function declaration and a `return` statement in the function body.

Comment: @goodvibration: heum.... I still have the error "abstract contrcat" 

Comment: @Endurs: That's because you haven't implemented in contract `IPES_coin` each one of the functions which are declared in contract `ERC20Interface` **precisely** as that function is declared!

Comment: @goodvibration: Where are the différences?